# Receiving Tomcat error in several versions of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Here is the error in my editor:

[image]

Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\dragrace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DragRaceRentalCars\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(JarResourceSet.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.modified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5608)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\dragrace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DragRaceRentalCars\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(JarResourceSet.java:119)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: I would guess that `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\dragrace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DragRaceRentalCars\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)` is the issue. Does that file exist? What should put it there - a compile or build process, or your manually copying it there?

Comment: The root cause is possibly the file permission problem. Is your workspace shared between different OS user account? is it copied from another system?